# Create directory and move tiles to it using Ruby FTP class

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I'm processing some files within my FTP server, when I'm done with the files I want to move them to a directory that will be created specifically for that batch.

The code creates the directory successfully but I'm missing something with the path to move the files.

**How can I get the name of the directory to add it to the path?**

```
ftp=Net::FTP.new
ftp.connect("...")
ftp.login('...', '...')

files = ftp.nlst("*.xml")


new_directory = ftp.mkdir(Time.now.to_s)

files.each do |file|
   ftp.rename(file, "/#{new_directory}/#{file}")
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to store the wrong value.

```
new_directory = Time.now.to_s
ftp.mkdir(new_directory)

files.each do |file|
   ftp.rename(file, "#{new_directory}/#{file}")
end
```